# jQuery add element in each loop

Tags: jquery, each

Getting a little headache with jQuery in my attempt to add a toggle button to each element that contains a specific class.
As i use jQuery's `.each(` , i was hoping to do it at the loop i add my identifier class.
But somehow it keeps append my html code in a loop to each `li` instead of the `li.has-children`

This is my current code:

```
    function addLevelClass($parent, level) {
      // fetch all the li's that are direct children of the ul
      var $children = $parent.children('li');
      // loop trough each li
      $children.each(function() {
        // get the ul that is a direct child of the li
        var $sublist = $(this).children('ul');
        // if an ul was found
        if ($sublist.length > 0) {
          $sublist.addClass('slideable-submenu');
          // add a class to the current li indicating there is a sub list
          $(this).addClass('has-children level-'+level);


          //last attempt before ask on SO
          if( $(this).hasClass('has-children level-'+level) ){
            $( 'li.has-children span a' ).after( '<span class="sub-menu-toggle"></span>');
          }

          // repeat the process for the sublist, but with the level one higher
          // = recursive function call
          addLevelClass($sublist, level+1);
        }
      });
    }

    // call the function to add level classes on the upper most ul
    addLevelClass($('.header-mobile-menu'), 0);
    //$( 'li.has-children span a' ).after( '<span class="sub-menu-toggle"></span>');//Adds toggle buttons everywhere
```

So the idea is to get:

```
$( 'li.has-children span a' ).after( '<span class="sub-menu-toggle"></span>');
```

In it's correct position.

Comment: Can you post markup? Also you don't need `if( $(this).hasClass('has-children level-'+level) )` as it's always going to be true

Comment: @SeanT , thanks for your help attempt (the fiddle was a pain and the answer came quicker). I did so many attempts like: `find('a')` but should have been `find('span:first')`. We keep learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to add a toggle button with each `<li>` that has a sub menu.

If so, I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gstarce3/1/) with some generic markup that might be helpful.

The only real change I made was how the toggle button is appended and I removed the recursive call back to itself.

Here is the updated code:

```
function addLevelClass($parent, level) {

      // fetch all the li's that are direct children of the ul
      var $children = $parent.children('li');

      // loop trough each li
      // here I added a check if level is defined, if not set it to 0, this way you don't have to pass it a value unless you want to start it somewhere
      var level = (typeof(level) !== 'undefined') ? level : 0;
      $children.each(function() {
        // get the ul that is a direct child of the li
        var $sublist = $(this).children('ul');
        // if an ul was found
        if ($sublist.length > 0) {


          $sublist.addClass('slideable-submenu');

          // add a class to the current li indicating there is a sub list
          $(this).addClass('has-children level-'+level).find('span:first').append( '<span class="sub-menu-toggle">toggle</span>');

          // increment level
          level++;

        }
      });
    }

    // call the function to add level classes on the upper most ul
    addLevelClass($('#parent ul'));
    //$( 'li.has-children span a' ).after( '<span class="sub-menu-toggle"></span>');//Adds toggle buttons everywhere
```

Comment: It works if i keep the recursive call, seems al i needed was: `$(this).addClass('has-children level-'+level).find('span:first').append( '<span class="sub-menu-toggle">toggle</span>');`

Comment: Reason i have to keep the recursive call is that it is a multi-level-menu generated via php. Good job!!! answer accepted.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped!